# URL address is Strikethrough when running Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running automation test on local url, after some time (happening randomly)
url is strike-through for unknown reason and due to that , the site keeps on loading and test fails.

[image]

using these confg-
**chrom**e-60.0.3xx 
**chromedriver**-2.29
**selenium webriver**- 2.53.x

Do anyone has some explanation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: its happen for me also.You can use retry class...

Comment: whats this class

Comment: is it help you?

Comment: I am using same configuration, it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found was quitting the chromedriver as there was multiple processes of chromedriver running.

Killing the process is best solution I get. Use the Task scheduler to end the process of chromedriver.

Comment: Yes @bot13 I got the same solution:)